# Regex to format file names and paths uniformly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to extract several file names from a string including possible path. The problem (for me) is that the string can have many variations and, if not present, a character must be inserted before the filename. I think the example below should make it easier to understand.

I have tried the following Spahetti code because I am not a regex profi and don't know how to perform multiple manipulations. Also in this script snippet the insertion of a character before the filename is missing. Note that I push every single filename in the `filenames` array

```
const regex = /@import(.*);/gm; const str = content; let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) regex.lastIndex++; // stop infinity loop
  // Init variable
  var filename = m[1];
  // Remove spaces
  filename = filename.trim();
  // Remove ', ", ` from first and last character
  if (filename.charAt(0) === "'" || filename.charAt(0) === '"' || filename.charAt(0) === "`") filename = filename.substr(1);
  if (filename.charAt(filename.length - 1) === "'" || filename.charAt(filename.length - 1) === '"' || filename.charAt(filename.length - 1) === "`") filename = filename.substring(0, filename.length - 1);;
  // Remove / from first character
  if (filename.charAt(0) === "/") filename = filename.substr(1);
  // Remove _ from first character
  if (filename.substr(filename.length - 3) !== ".js") filename = filename+".js";
  // Push
  filenames.push(filename);
}
```

**Here now the initial string:**

```
// i am a 'comment'
@import 'jquery-3.3.1';
@import   "_slick.js";
@import            `subfolder/_analytics`;
@import            `/subfolder/bootstrap`;



@import     `subfolder/javascript/marvin.js`;
```

This should be included in the `filenames` array after string manipulation:

```
[ '_jquery-3.3.1.js', '_slick.js', 'subfolder/_analytics.js', 'subfolder/_bootstrap.js', 'subfolder/javascript/_marvin.js' ]
```

Comment: So, what is the question ? How to add `_` at the start of the filename ?

Comment: I'd get the `_` in there, too. But i don't like how the snippet looks like. So my question is rather how can i realize the whole snippet more prettier? Closer to best practice. How would a variant with more regex work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like this

```
@import[^"'`]*["'`]\/*([^;]+)["'`][^;]*;
```

This one extracts the path without the quotes or the leading `/`

Here is an example:

```js
const str = `
// i am a 'comment'
@import 'jquery-3.3.1';
@import   "_slick.js";
@import            \`subfolder/_analytics\`;
@import            \`/subfolder/bootstrap\`;



@import     \`subfolder/javascript/marvin.js\`;`

const regex = /@import[^"'`]*["'`]\/*([^;]+)["'`][^;]*;/gm
const paths = [];


while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  let path = m[1]
  if (!path.endsWith(".js")) {
    path = `${path}.js`
  }

  path = path.replace(/(\/|^)([^_][^\/]*\.js)$/, "$1_$2")
  paths.push(path)
}

console.log(paths)
```

Comment: This definitely looks better! Thanks to you! By regex101 I could understand most of what the regex do. But I still have one question. What exactly does `[^/]+` in the second regex? (Edit: I didn't know endsWith. Cool function!)

Comment: @DieterInformation It means any character except `/` once or multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capture group to capture either one of the quotes and then use a backreference to the first capturing group to make sure the opening char matches the closing char.

Then you could split on a forward slash and modify the last item accordingly. To get your values you could use a second capturing group.

```
@import.*?([`"'])(.*?)\1
```

That will match:

- `@import` Match literally
- `.*?` Match any char non greedy
- `` ([`"']) `` Match on of the chars listed in the character class
- `(.*?)` Capture in group 2 any char non greedy
- `\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW9CxM/1)

```js
const regex = /@import.*?([`"'])(.*?)\1/g;
const str = `// i am a 'comment'
@import 'jquery-3.3.1';
@import   "_slick.js";
@import            \`subfolder/_analytics\`;
@import            \`/subfolder/bootstrap\`;



@import     \`subfolder/javascript/marvin.js\`;`;
let m;
let res = [];
let checkUnderscore = x => !x.startsWith("_") ? "_" + x : x;
let checkExtension = x => !x.endsWith(".js") ? x + ".js" : x;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  let parts = m[2].replace(/^\/+/, '').split("/");
  let length = parts.length;
  res.push(
    parts.map((part, i) => i === length - 1 ? checkExtension(checkUnderscore(part)) : part).join('/')
  );
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately there is no _ added in your variant. I have tested the variant of Titus and think that this fits better to my needs.

Comment: Awesome! Now it runs also with your variant :) I must consider myself which I use. The question is now which variant is more resource saving?!